# Small world network regime

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, network-theory

I have recently read

- Watts, D., Strogatz, S., *Collective dynamics of ‘small-world’ networks*, Nature **393** (1998) pp. 440–442, doi:[10.1038/30918](https://doi.org/10.1038/30918),

on small-world networks, and is still not very clear to me how is the "small-world network regime" defined. Meaning that for a fixed value of vertices $N$ and a node degree $k$, what is the intermediate region of $0 < p < 1$ for which the Watts-Strogatz model is a small-world network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An increase of the "rewiring probability" $p$ (the probability that an edge is disconnected from one of its nodes and then randomly connected to another node) reduces both the mean path length $L$ and the [clustering coeffcient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient) $C$. There is a range of $p$ where the path length has been reduced substantially while the clustering coefficient is still close to the $p=0$ value. In that range of $p$ the network is called a small-world network.

There is no unique way to quantify that $p$-range. Wikipedia lists [three different criteria.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-world_network#Properties_of_small-world_networks)

The figure below shows how $L$ and $C$ decrease with increasing $p$. The shaded region would be the "small-world network" region, but obviously this is not a sharply bound region. [click on the figure to enter the applet and see how the network changes as you slide $p$]

[image]

*Note: "path length" counts each edge as being of length 1, irrespective of the length of the bond.*

Comment: Great to know about the Math Insight collection!

Comment: Thanks Carlo, when I read the paper I was expecting to find a theoretical property related to the small world network regime. Such as in the ER models where probability theory and graph theory was used for identifying the appearance of certain properties that characterize such graphs. I guess this is not the case as the Clustering Coefficient and the characteristic path length are independent structural properties? I hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: the characterization of a small-world network as being "highly clustered, like regular lattices, yet have small characteristic path lengths, like random graphs" is a qualitative one; this is different from a scale-free network, which has a power law distribution of nodes degree and therefore satisfies a quantitative criterion.